# How do I add a config list am I doing it wrongly?

Tags: lua

The issue I am recieving is making a txt files contents readable in a listed format
such as:

- word1
- word2
- word3

if a user were to have said any of the words/or phrases then they would get a response otherwise the program would wait for a valid reply from the blacklisted word file.

```
local valid;
repeat
local reply = io.read()
file = io.open('blacklist.txt', "r+")
file:read()
file:close()
   -- list would equal contents within blacklist.txt
if reply == list then
  valid = reply
  print("Kicking User From Game")
  --game.kick.saidUser
else
--do nothing and wait for valid response
end
until valid;
```

Comment: You described situation, but didn't point out where is the problem. Which part is not working and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:read()` reads one line from the file and discards it.

I think you want to read the whole contents of the file into `list` with

```
list = file:read("*a")
```

Then you want to check whether `reply` is in the `list` with

```
if list:match("\n"..reply.."\n") then
```

You may want to read the `list` outside the loop and to prepend `\n` to `list` to make the pattern matching simpler.